# Why does running Hive with aggregation functions in queries fails

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, hql

For example, computing the average statistic using `select avg(salary) from employees;` always gives me this error:

```
hive (default)> select avg(salary) from employees;
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala.collection.Iterable
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.spark.GenSparkProcContext.<init>(GenSparkProcContext.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.spark.SparkCompiler.generateTaskTree(SparkCompiler.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.TaskCompiler.compile(TaskCompiler.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(SemanticAnalyzer.java:11253)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.CalcitePlanner.analyzeInternal(CalcitePlanner.java:286)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:258)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1236)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:821)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.Iterable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:609)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:850)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:829)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:329)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:809)
    ... 23 more
```

I have attempted many times to tackle the error after lots of googling with no luck. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I've tried all of those solutions, none of which seems to apply to my situation unfortunately. I'm running out of ideas of how to figure out what could possibly give rise to this issue.

Plus, a simple `join` operation also does not work, throwing me exactly the same error.

Comment: Check [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/hive-spark-configuration-common-issues-mohamed-k/) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114905/hive-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-scala-co)

Comment: I've tried those already, but it doesn't work, throwing me the same error again.