# Hive-On-Spark - Error when running queries after execution.engine changed to Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql

I originally wrote some Hive queries to run on Tez. As the queries are getting more complex and much more data, they are taking way to long. Because of that, I am now trying to run hive-on-spark to hopefully speed up the queries.

when I run 
set hive.execution.engine=spark;
I get no errors - and it shows successful.

Whenever I try to query, for example,

Select * from XX.TEST AAB
left join XX.TEST2 AA on AAB.ATTR1 = AA.ATTR2

I get the following error:
Error running query: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Iterable

Also it seems like a simple select statement from a table works but not with anything else?

If I attempt to run this on Tez, I am not getting any error at all.

I have tried to google the error but I am not able to find anything to resolve this. Can anyone help?

Comment: You will need spark jars in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this post helps

[Hive error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/Iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114905/hive-error-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-scala-co)